# Equivalent condition for consistent Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A be $m \times n $ matrix and B be $n \times m $ matrix, $x \in
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ , $y,b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then
>
> 1 (false). Ax = b is consistent iff BAx = Bb is consistent
>
> 2 (false). Ax = b is consistent iff A'Ax = A'b is consistent
>
> 3 (true). Ax = b is consistent iff AA'y = b is consistent

What I know: the LHS means rankA = rank (A|b). Also, rankA = rank AA' = rank A'A. Still, I don't know how to show which of the above is false/true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Take $B = 0$. Then the condition becomes $0=0$ which is alwyas true, and therefore cannot be equivalent to the consistency of $Ax = b$.

2) Is false because it always has a solution; in fact this is what we do when we want to find the minimum square solution ;-)

3) Finally the third is true, if there is a solution $y$ we set $x = A'y$ and we have a solution for our first problem. Conversely, if there is a solution $x$ to the problem $Ax = b$, we find $y$ such that $A'y = x$. We have to show that $y$ exists. Putting it in the equation $Ax=b$ we get $AA'y = b$ that has a solution because $b \in Col(A)$, and so $b \in Col(AA')$

Comment: could you please elaborate why 2 always has a solution?

Comment: @push Those are called normal equations, and finding a solution to that is equivalent to find the solution to $Ax = b_h$, where $b_h$ is the projection of $b$ on $Col(A)$. Clearly the latter system has always a solution. You can find the proof in any algebra book! :-)